# The input to the CNN of Conv1D

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm working in the field of machine learning.

For the stronger Network, I'm going to adopt the techniques concerning Conv1D.

The input data is an one-dimension list data so I just would've thought that Conv1D is the best choice.

What would happen if the input size is `(1, 740)`? Would it be okay the input channel is 1?

I mean,I have a feeling that the `(1, 740)` tensor's conv1D output should be the same with that of a simple Linear networks.

Of course I'll also include other conv1d layer, like below.

```
self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5)
self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64,out_channels=64, kernel_size=5)
self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5)
self.conv4 = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5)
```

Would it make sense when an input channel is 1?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine.
Note that the input of Conv1D should be (B, N, M), where B is the batch size, N is the number of channels (e.g. for RGB is 3) and M is the number of features.
The out_channels refers to the number of 5x5 filters to use. look at the output shape of the following code:

```py
k = nn.Conv1d(1,64,kernel_size=5)
input = torch.randn(1, 1, 740)
print(k(input).shape) # -> torch.Size([1, 64, 736])
```

The 736 is the result of not using padding the dimension isn't kept.

Answer (score 0):

The [nn.Conv1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html) layer takes an input of shape `(b, c, w)` (where `b` is the batch size, `c` the number of channels, and `w` the input width). Its kernel size is one-dimensional. It performs a convolution operation over the input dimension (batch and channel axes aside). This means the kernel will apply the same operation over the whole input (wether 1D, 2D, or 3D). Like a 'sliding window'. As such, it only has `kernel_size` parameters. This is the main characteristic of a convolution layer.

Conv1d allows to extract features on the input regardless of where it's located in the input data: at the beginning or at the end of your `w`-width input. This would make sense if your input is temporal (input sequence over time) or spatial data (an image).

On the other hand, a [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) takes a 1D tensor as input and returns another 1D tensor. You could consider `w` to be the number of neurons. You would end up having `w*output_dim` parameters. If your input contains components which are independant from one another (like a One/Multi-Hot-Encoding) then a fully connected layer as `nn.Linear` implements would be prefered.

These two behave differently. When using a `nn.Linear` - in scenarios where you should use a `nn.Conv1d` - your training would ideally result in having neurons of equal weights, if that makes sense... but you probably won't. Fully-densely-connected layers were used in the past in deep learning for computer vision. Today convolutions are used because there are much more efficient and suitable for these types of tasks.